# apache pig & piggybank avro union types

Tags: apache-pig, avro

I have a record of union type of

```
union {TypeA, TypeB, TypeC, TypeD, TypeE} mydata;
```

I have the serialized data in avro format, however when I am trying to use piggybank.jar's AvroStorage function to load the avro data, it gives me the following error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: We don't accept schema containing generic unions.
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroSchema2Pig.convert(AvroSchema2Pig.java:54)
    at org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage.getSchema(AvroStorage.java:384)
    at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOLoad.getSchemaFromMetaData(LOLoad.java:174)
    ... 23 more
```

So, after reading the piggybank source code here https://github.com/triplel/pig/blob/branch-0.12/contrib/piggybank/java/src/main/java/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/avro/AvroStorageUtils.java

```
    /** determine whether a union is a nullable union;
    * note that this function doesn't check containing
    * types of the input union recursively. */
    public static boolean isAcceptableUnion(Schema in) {
        if (! in.getType().equals(Schema.Type.UNION))
           return false;

    List<Schema> types = in.getTypes();
    if (types.size() <= 1) {
        return true;
    } else if (types.size() > 2) {
        return false; /*contains more than 2 types */
    } else {
        /* one of two types is NULL */
        return types.get(0).getType().equals(Schema.Type.NULL) || types.get(1) .getType().equals(Schema.Type.NULL);
    }
}
```

basically piggybank's AvroStorage does not support more than 2 union types, I am wondering what is the idea behind this decision? Why not just make it compatible with Avro?

Comment: can you define what you mean by "union type" ?

Comment: "union type" refers to the arbitrary types in an Avro union, the types you specifies in the union, like in my example at the top. Apologies for being a little ambiguous.

Comment: Voted to close as I don't believe that the question of 'why' software is made as it is, is ontopic for this site.